# Near Dupliate Document detection using TextProfileSignature fnv-text-profile-signature

Tags: solr, duplicates, nutch

I have numerous documents already converted to text. Many of these documents are harvested web pages. Apache Tika is used for some of this (if anyone cares).

I would like a Java Library that I can use to find near duplicates (NDD). I could provide you with links to different methods and documentation on this, but, this question is specifically about the use of TextProfileSignature. That said, if I am missing something obvious from another existing package, I am rather new to Near Duplicate Detection.

I first found the TextProfileSignature class in SOLR

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_2_1/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/TextProfileSignature.html

It is stated that the algorithm was taken from Clutch

org.apache.nutch.crawl.TextProfileSignature

And then to muddle the waters, it looks like the implementation is actually available directly on GitHub

https://github.com/casetext/fnv-text-profile-signature

It is clear to me that if I install SOLR/Lucene, when I feed documents into SOLR I can configure it to run NDD and populate the text profile signature. For my uses, I was hoping to not run my documents through SOLR/Lucene, but rather, simply generate the text profile signature.

I was not able to find any example code using any instances of this outside of the provided packages. While preparing to ask this question, I found the GITHUB code, and it appears as though this is probably the best way for me to go since it looks like it will provide a stand-alone package without trying to extract JARS from the much larger SOLR package.

I have followed many trails and this is how far I have gone.... So, any example code to use these classes in your own code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it is very easy to call the code on github. Understand that I did all of this on a Fedora Linux computer. I did the following:

I built the code using "./gradlew build"

I added the generated JAR file to my local maven repository: mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/home/andy/fnv-text-profile-signature-1.0.jar -DgroupId=com.casetext -DartifactId=textprofilesignature -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar

After setting the dependency in my POM file, I can use the following trivial code:

```
TextProfileSignature signer = new TextProfileSignature(quantizationRate, minimumTokenLength);
signer.addText(s);
String signature = signer.getSignature();
```

Very easy to do. I found that I could process roughly 70 documents a second. I tested against 5200 documents. For me, this was pretty slow, so I looked deeper.

I found out that I can directly call the SOLR / LUCENE version with no problem.

First, I added this to my POM file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I included some dependencies:

```
import org.apache.solr.update.processor.TextProfileSignature;
import org.apache.solr.common.params.ModifiableSolrParams;
```

The SOLR version returns byte[] rather than string, and it accepts no parameters

```
    TextProfileSignature signer = new TextProfileSignature();
    signer.init(params);
    signer.add(s);
    byte[] signature = signer.getSignature();
```

If you do not use init, you have the default parameter values, which is probably acceptable for most uses. This is how I initialized the parameter object to use my values:

```
    ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
    params.set("minTokenLen", minimumTokenLength);
    params.set("quantRate", Float.toString(quantizationRate));
```

I determined this by trial and error, and also by looking at some source code. I have not rigorously verified that I am properly setting the parameters, but the number of unique documents returned is 4691 as opposed to 4690; close enough for me to accept it as correct, especially since the slower version generates a 127-bit FNV-1 hash and the SOLR version seems to be generating an MD5, but again, I did not push too deeply to see.

So ultimately, why do I care about using the SOLR version, because it seems to have processed about 10,000 documents a second rather than 70 documents a second; but I need to run a few more tests to see if I still agree with this number.